# How to make a running docker container to detached mode?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I have ran a docker container / docker compose service without `-d` option, how do I change the running instance to detached mode? Is it possible?

```
# docker-compose up myservice &
[2] 12345
```

Answer (score 2):

Docker supports a keyboard combination to gracefully detach from a container. Press Ctrl-P, followed by Ctrl-Q, to detach from your connection.

To change the configuration of a previously created container you can use docker update

```
docker update [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
```

Note:
The docker update and docker container update commands are not supported for Windows containers.

Comment: Have tried. The detach keys / Ctrl-P Ctrl-Q seem only working in terminal of running docker container. What about ``docker run`` without ``--it``?

Comment: " docker update [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...] " as specified above.